# Why does stringstream yields strange values?

Tags: c++, stringstream

So, I'm trying to use a stringstream in my program, in order to get some formatted string (esp. because I need to convert numbers to string).

The thing is, my program crashes, and when I debug it with Visual Studio, in my Spy window, I see that my stringstream's string buffer yields (when trying to add "Framerate" to it):

"FramerateÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍýýýý««««««««îþîþ"

Code :

```
std::stringstream s;
s << "Framerate";
```

My code then will crash the moment I try to get the associated string...
I can't find any explanation for this, nor a problem with my code...

EDIT: Turns out these characters aren't the issue, and that the stringstream returns the expected string with `str()`.

Comment: regarding the crash, **show the code**. regarding the arbitrary contents of unused parts of a buffer, what did you expect.

Comment: My guess is that you don't provide \0 char at the end, but I cannot tell without more code.

Comment: @Benjamin why should you provide a `\0` at the end?

Comment: Because when you send char* to stringstream, end of char* object is distinguished by the \0 sign. If JBL does as he wrote, s << "Framerate";, he already has implicit \0 at the end of const char*, so there's no problem there.

Comment: maybe you should give us a little bit more code...We could keep hypothetizing on what we have for now, but that would not be very helpful...

Comment: The way variables are shown is just an internal problem of MSVS. I've met with it, and just like you I worried what had happened, but the string was returned OK.

Your problem must lie somewhere else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`stringstream`'s internal buffer need not be null terminated. However, when you call `str()` on the `stringstream` object, you will get a null terminated string. It's highly likely the cause of your crash is elsewhere.

Comment: Indeed... I just realized that, and though I still don't know where does the crash comes from, when I get the string associated with the stream, the weird characters are gone... I may have jumped a bit too fast to the conclusion that my crash was obviously due to these weird chars...

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio 2015 version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3 it looks like std::strstream does not ensure that the data returned by 'str()' is null terminated.

I ran a test with:

```
`std::strstream s;
 s << "the cow jumped over the moon!";
 return s.str();`
```

and got:
    `the cow jumped over the moon!===zzzz`

adding `s.write("", 1);` before the return fixed my output but is very unpleasant.

Comment: I ran in to this right after I commented: "Before any call to str() that uses the result as a C string, the buffer must be null-terminated, typically with std::ends."   I was also confused by stringstream vs strstream.  Leaving this here in case anybody else runs in to this.